# Simplify equation to isolate variable by itself

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I feel really dumb for not being able to figure this out:

```
12/x = (.1 + (.08/10) + 1 + .08)
```

How can I get this equation to have `x` all by itself IE (`x=....`)

Comment: Hint: Simplify the RHS, inverting both sides and then multiplying by 12.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{12}{x} = (.1 + (.08/10) + 1 + .08)$$

As Luis suggested, we can simplify the expression on the right:

$$.1 + (.08/10) + 1 + .09 = .1 + .008 + 1 + .09 = 1.198$$

Now, the original equation becomes $$\frac{12}{x} = 1.198$$

We can multiply by $x$ on both sides to get

$$\frac{12}{x} \cdot x = 1.198 x$$

Now, as long as $x \neq 0$, we can cancel the $x$s on the left. Now we have

$$12 = 1.198 x$$

We divide by $1.198$ on both sides, so

$$\frac{12}{1.198} = \frac{1.198x}{1.198}$$

On the right, the $1.198$s cancel, and we are left with

$$x = \frac{12}{1.198} = \frac{6000}{599} \approx 10.017$$

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The number on the right is just a number. Hence you can just cross mutiply. Since I am lazy, I will call the number on the right $b$. Then you just get $x=\frac{12}{b}$. You can also simplify the quantity on the right (Please do so, it will look prettier =]).